# Estimation of the number of local extrema

Tags: reference-request, critical-point-theory

I have a question about a simple proposition, I suppose that this is something
well-known or a special case of something well-known:

Let $D\subset\mathbb{R}^{2}$ be the closed unit disk in the plane and
$f:D\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a smooth function. Suppose that the restriction
$f|_{\mathbb{S}^{1}}$ has exactly $n$ local extrema, but none of them is a
local extremum of $f$. Then the function $f$ has at least $\frac{n}{2}+1$
local extrema inside $D$.

Note that it follows from the condition that the level line of $f$ at a local
extremum of $f|_{\mathbb{S}^{1}}$ touches the boundary from inside. Some
examples are given below as level lines diagrams.

[image: drawing]

Here closed level lines correspond to local extrema of $f$ and crossing points of level lines correspond to saddles (possibly degenerated).
As the condition is simple and clear and the proof is quite elementary*, I
intend to propose this at a student competition. However, if this is
well-known or folklore, it might not be suitable to propose it, so any
references are welcome.

*/ In fact I have an elementary proof of a weaker form of the statement, claiming the existence of at least $\frac{n}{2}+1$ critical points of $f$ inside $D$.

Remarks. 1) This proposition may be completed by adding a second part:
Let $\varphi:\mathbb{S}^{1}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a smooth function with
$n$ local extrema, then it may be extended to a smooth $f:D\rightarrow
\mathbb{R}$ satisfying the above conditions with exactly $\frac{n}{2}+1$
local extrema (and thus lying in the interior of $D$). Presumably this is
true, but I don't have a proof.

2) For a given even $n$, we may ask about the number of (topologically)
different diagrams up to symmetry (rotation, reflection) with exactly
$\frac{n}{2}+1$ local extrema and without other critical points; but it seems
to be a very hard task.

Comment: Those pictures do not really look like a proof to me. Besides, to make the statement closer to the truth, one should count the extrema with some carefully defined multiplicities; otherwise, there may be just a single extremum unside. The multiplicity is, probably, the index of the gradient vector field, in which case the statement becomes just the Poincaré–Hopf theorem with boundary.

Comment: @ Alex Degtyarev: I don't think that "there may be just a single extremum unside" - if $P$ and $Q$ are an absolute minimum and an absolute maximum of the restriction, then the conditions guarantee at least 2 absolute extrema of $f$ inside $D$ - a minimum and a maximum.

Comment: If you allow degenerate minima, and (w.l.o.g.) $\phi>0$ we can take $f(x)=x^2\phi(x/|x|)$.

Comment: @PietroMajer maybe it's the same example :) $f=r^2+r^3\sin(n\theta)$ in the polar coordinates. If my math is correct, it has no critical points in $0<r<2/3$. Rescale it to the unit disk.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I see that you inhibit **extrema**, not just critical points on the boundary. Then, indeed, there must be two.

Comment: @ Pietro Majer: This is supposed to be a counter-example, right? But I don't think that it satisfies the boundary conditions, seems to me that even each local extremum of $\varphi$ is a local extremum of $f$ as well.

Comment: Add: At least at the local maxima of $\varphi$ the condition fails.

Comment: OK; actually I understood "inside" as "in the interior", in the open disk, $f$  has a unique critical point  (the origin). At the boundary f has n/2 local maxima.

Comment: But the boundary condition fails there. By the way a function $f$ satisfying the above conditions looks a little bit "strange".

Comment: OK, I think I agree with your statement, but certainly not with the proof :) It appears that the index of $\nabla f$ is $+1$ at each extremum and negative at other critical points. It is also more or less clear that the rotation number along the boundary is $n/2$. (The lack of extrema inhibits "negative" rotation.) So, we're done.

Comment: The rotation number along the boundary is $n/2$, right. But the fact that "the index of ∇f is +1 at each extremum and negative at other critical points" needs a proof. On the other hand, I wish to avoid concepts like "index" and "rotation number". Anyway, if your arguments are correct, I will accept that the statement is "obvious" :)

Comment: Right. These are certainly true for "decent" functions, at least, for those for which your pictures work :) Say, about an extremum, **assuming** a nice level curve nearby, $\nabla f$ is normal and pointing in the same direction (unless $0$), hence index is $1$.

Comment: By the way, I initially formulated the statement in a weaker form - "there exist at least $n/2+1$ critical points"; in this variant we may assume a finite number of critical points of $f$ and all level curves are "nice". Now I realize that my elementary proof works in fact without problems for this variant, so I'll may be go back to it.

Comment: Add: But the stronger form with $n/2+1$ extrema remains unclear to me.

Comment: I think it would be good to include the precise definition of local extrema for this question, both for f on D and on S^1.